# Why css & image get distorted on URL rewrite in asp.net?

Tags: css, asp.net, url-rewriting, imageurl

I have a .aspx page which shows item list. Currently it displays `www.site.com/Catalog.aspx?mid=228` which need to be `www.site.com/CellPhone/blackbery/sprint/Q10.aspx`. All items are displayed in DataList and on button click the Hyperlink redirect to `Catalog.aspx` with query string 'id' which is the device id.

Now, I have build URL for LinkButton as `'CellPhone/blackbery/sprint/228'` dynamically and for other items too.

**Above link redirect and URL changes but css get disturbed. & i want to dynamically rewrite all links and not to hardcode as above.**

**css Reference:**

```
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/reset_font_grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/inner-pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**Catalog.aspx**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" NavigateUrl="/cellphone/blackberry/sprint/228.aspx">Show Cellphones asdfsdf</asp:HyperLink>
```

**Global.asax**

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<script runat="server">
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoute(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    void RegisterRoute(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-hide-remove-ASPX-extension-in-URL-in-ASPNet.aspx
        routes.MapPageRoute("44", "{cat}/{carrier}/{devices}/{id}.aspx", "~/Catalog.aspx");
    }
}
```

**All works fine but just the css on the page & images is not applied!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use  `ResolveUrl`

**Example :**

```
<link href="<%= ResolveUrl("css/layout.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Please let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: hi @Amarsinh Pol thanks for replying this works fine! :)

Answer (score 2):

just change the `href` of the `CSS` relative to it's `root` not from current location,

change

```
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/reset_font_grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/inner-pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to

```
<link href="/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/reset_font_grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/inner-pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

`/css/layout.css` mean that the file `layout.css` is inside folder `css` in the `root` wherever you call it, for example if your page is like this

```
http://www.example.com/product/smartphone/blackberry
```

if you use

```
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it will look for the `css` with this route `root/product/smartphone/blackberry/css/layout.css`, because there's no file in that folder or route, it can't load the `CSS` file which cause your `CSS` get disturbed.

Comment: hi @Kyoijimaru, i tried this too..and this too works..! so +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way should be add a is not a file condition:

```
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
```